# including cmath over math.h is causing incorrect results

Tags: c++, std, math.h, cmath

Edited for test case and compiler inconsistency. Recently I made a change to use the more modern < cmath > instead of < math.h >. While this compiled just fine as expected with no warnings, this one-line change for one file caused my test cases to fail. From my understanding, cmath just puts most of the functions/variables in the std namespace, and I don't make any changes to that namespace.

I'll note I am using

- sqrt
- abs (since I am using doubles here I would assume the compiler would automatically use the cmath/math.h form, not stdlib)
- tan

out of any files potentially affected by this one-line change on one file. I do have a different file that is already using cmath, but does not affect the testing.

A test case with

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
int main() {

    double x = -0.546;
    double y = abs( x / sqrt(x*x + 1.0));
    double z = std::abs( x / sqrt(x*x + 1.0));

    std::cout << "Variable value is " << x << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Value of function using cmath " << z << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Value of function using stdlib " << y << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

gives output

```
Value is -0.546
Value of function using cmath 0.479221
Value of function using stdlib 0
```

on compiler (GCC) 8.3.1 20191121. Curiously, this is not the output on C++ shell, instead keeping the value of the function non-zero.

Comment: You seem to mention cmake in a few places where cmath makes more sense. Might be worth cleaning up the question.

Comment: And editing in a [mre] as well.

Comment: `cmath` also adds in some fun lil' templates. I've seen some interesting behaviours with `std::pow` templated wrapping round `::pow` behaving differently from `::pow` for reasons I was never able to understand. You may have encountered something similar, but the proof of the program is in the coding, to deliberately misquote a favored line of my grandmother's.

Comment: If you have `using namespace std` it can pick different overloads, e.g. cmath defines [tan(double) and tan(float)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/tan), but there is no function overloads in C language at all and it defines separate `tan(double)` and `tanf(float)` functions.

Comment: @paxdiablo, fixed to use cmath

Comment: @sweenish, this is really more of question requiring a method or heuristic answer, mainly because I have a large data set going through the equations, and I'm not sure if some combination of variables may be an issue related to cmath vs math.h. I can give you a huge list with the equations in question, but overall the example may be difficult to reproduce.

Comment: @dewaffled I am not using `using namespace std` .    But I'm guessing that would be helpful here.

Comment: If debugging was easy programmers would be a dime-a-dozen. Do what you can to isolate the sucker and you'll have a good Stack Overflow question. Leave it like this and there isn't much we can do but pitch guesses at you, and that's something Stackoverflow's not that good at.

Comment: I didn't request your code. I requested a [mre]. Being able to reproduce the error in a smaller program is overall beneficial.

Comment: Can you extract 1 failing test case as a [mcve] that we can look at on [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/).  Please read [mcve].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C++ standard library has defined overloads for `std::abs` that accept floating point types. These are declared in the `std` namespace only, as to not pollute the global namespace. [More info on cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fabs).

The same is not true for `abs` in the global namespace. Its origin is on `stdlib.h`. Since `stdlib.h` is a C library, and C does not support function overloads, the versions for floating point are defined instead as `fabs` and `fabsf` for `double` and `float`, respectively.

What you are actually doing when calling `abs` (in the global namespace) with a floating point value is casting that value to an integer. Since the value is guaranteed to be smaller than `1` in your example, that means that you are essentially always passing `0` as the argument.

If you turn on warnings (specifically `-Wconversion`), [the compiler will warn you about this](https://godbolt.org/z/dsxfbaP11):

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:6:23: warning: conversion from 'double' to 'int' may change value [-Wfloat-conversion]
     double y = abs( x / sqrt(x*x + 1.0));
                     ~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Curiously, this is a case where declaring `using namespace std;` would "solve the problem". Since `std::abs(double)` is a better overload, it would be chosen by overload resolution if the namespace `std` is imported into the global namespace. Not that I'm advocating doing this - it will have several other side effects that you may not be aware about. So the best thing to do is to either use `std::abs` explicitly, or only importing it specifically, and in a narrower scope (e.g.: placing `using std::abs;` in your function's scope).